# How to extract references into one external file in angularjs unit test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, typescript, jasmine

I am using Jasmine to writing Unit Test for my AngularJS project, But it seem dulicate code because in each spec file I have to add some references like below

```
/// <reference path="../../../bower_components/jasmine/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js" />
/// <reference path="../../../bower_components/jasmine/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine-html.js" />
/// <reference path="../../../bower_components/jasmine/lib/jasmine-core/boot.js" />
/// <reference path="../../../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" />
/// <reference path="../../../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js" />
/// <reference path="../../../bower_components/angular/angular.js" />
/// <reference path="../../../vendors/js/jBox.js" />
/// <reference path="../../../bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js" />
```

And so on

Is there a way extract the references into one external file, then I just add only that file on each test spec file.

Comment: What version of typescript are you using? You can create a typings file that is used by all of your scripts, but this feature is only available in newer versions of typescript.

Comment: Hi Andrew, I am using typescript version 1.7. Can you help me explain more detail the way you suggested. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use [typings](https://github.com/typings/typings) to manage your third party type libraries. It works like this (copied from the [typings quickstart guide](https://github.com/typings/typings#quick-start)):

```
# Install Typings CLI utility.
npm install typings --global

# Search for definitions.
typings search tape

# Find an available definition (by name).
typings search --name react

# If you use the package as a module:
# Install non-global typings (defaults to "npm" source, configurable through `defaultSource` in `.typingsrc`).
typings install debug --save

# If you use the package through script tag, or
# it is part of the environment, or

# the non-global typings is not yet available:
typings install dt~mocha --global --save

# Install typings from particular registry.
typings install env~atom --global --save
typings install npm~bluebird --save

# Use `typings/index.d.ts` (in `tsconfig.json` or as a `///` reference).
cat typings/index.d.ts
```

Then, once you have done this, either in every file you put a `///` reference to `typings/index.d.ts` in every test file. Or (this is better) put a reference to `typings/index.d.ts` in your tsconfig file like this:

```
{
  "files": [
    "typings/index.d.ts"
  ]
}
```